# Facebook group message on website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Following [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-messenger-website/29136/) tutorial will allow you to make a **send button** on your website and will send message directly to your fb page.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '95100348886',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-page" 
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XZY/" 
     data-tabs="messages" 
     data-width="400" 
     data-height="300" 
     data-small-header="true">
  <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote></blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

So that is the whole code. 
Now, Is there a way to do it like a group message on our own fb account (not fb page).
Example: When they send a message on website, me and my wife could read it (as a group). Is it possible. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

That is a Page plugin, only built for Pages. User to User (or Group) messaging is not possible with the API. You can use the Send Dialog, but people would need to be your friend on Facebook and they would need to fill in your name(s) when the Dialog pops up.

Comment: That is what I have read from the Docs. I thought it would be possible.